# get object value inside function coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

```
title = ->
  $("#post_title").keyup ->
    @value
```

When I try to call to `title()` function I'm getting `[object Object]`.

I have to add to the function value to this code:

```
"<li>" + "<div class='btn-group'>" + "<a href='/en" + "/posts/preview_search/" + "?post[title]=" +  title() + "</a>" + "</div>" + "</li>"
```

How can I get the `@value` returned by the object instead of the object?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want that function to do? Listen for a keyup event, or return a value?

Comment: I want get the current value of `#post_title` input text when a user is writting. I want that the function return the current `#post_title` value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyup event will happen *after* the function returns, therefore it can't be assigned to `title` using the function's return value. One way would be to do whatever you need to do with `title` inside the function:

```
$("#post_title").keyup ->
  title = @value
  # use title
```

Comment: I have added more info to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @hyperrjas, the answer would still be the same. This is an asynchronous operation. You can't obtain a result until a result becomes available...

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
title = ->
      $("#post_title").keyup (e) ->
        $(e.target).attr 'value'
```